# Suggestions to speed up `np.ctypeslib.as_array`

Tags: python, ctypes, numpy-ndarray

I need to convert ctypes pointers to numpy array, so that C functions could invoke Python functions. The complication here is that I need to do it many-many times as the Python functions are callbacks for a computational algorithm in C.

The problem is that `numpy.ctypeslib.as_array` is somewhat slow - it takes time on the order of 10 ms. I have tried several different approaches (using `np.ctypeslib.as_array`, `np.frombuffer`, working with `PyMemoryView_FromMemory`) but they all stay on the same order of magnitude for run time.

Does anyone know any tricks to make conversion from `ctypes` pointers to `np.ndarray`s faster? Thank you!

This is the script that I have used:

```py
import ctypes
import time

import numpy as np


class OIFArrayF64(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("nd", ctypes.c_int),
        ("dimensions", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long)),
        ("data", ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
    ]


len = 10_000
x = np.random.rand(len)

arr = ctypes.pointer(
    OIFArrayF64(
        1,
        ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_long(len)),
        x.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)),
    )
)

print("Passing LP_c_double pointer to np.ctypeslib.as_array")
begin = time.time()
arr1 = np.ctypeslib.as_array(arr.contents.data, shape=[len])
end = time.time()
print(f"Elapsed time: {end - begin}")
print(f"First element of the array is {arr1[0]}")

arr_type = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double * len)

print("Passing ctypes array to np.ctypeslib.as_array")
begin = time.time()
arr_ctypes = ctypes.cast(arr.contents.data, arr_type).contents
arr2 = np.ctypeslib.as_array(arr_ctypes, shape=[len])
end = time.time()
print(f"Elapsed time: {end - begin}")
print(f"First element of the array is {arr2[0]}")

print("Using np.frombuffer and reshape")
begin = time.time()
arr_ctypes = ctypes.cast(arr.contents.data, arr_type).contents
arr3 = np.frombuffer(arr_ctypes, dtype=np.float64, count=len)
np.reshape(arr3, (len,))
end = time.time()
print(f"Elapsed time: {end - begin}")
print(f"First element of the array is {arr3[0]}")

print("Using PyMemoryView_FromMemory")
begin = time.time()
buf_fn = ctypes.pythonapi.PyMemoryView_FromMemory
buf_fn.restype = ctypes.py_object
buf_fn.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_long]
buffer = buf_fn(arr.contents.data, len * np.dtype(np.float64).itemsize)
arr4: np.ndarray = np.ndarray([len], dtype=np.float64, buffer=buffer)
end = time.time()
print(f"Elapsed time: {end - begin}")
print(f"First element of the array is {arr4[0]}")
```

with the following results:

```
Passing LP_c_double pointer to np.ctypeslib.as_array
Elapsed time: 5.1021575927734375e-05
First element of the array is 0.5938379332312543
Passing ctypes array to np.ctypeslib.as_array
Elapsed time: 7.867813110351562e-06
First element of the array is 0.5938379332312543
Using np.frombuffer and reshape
Elapsed time: 1.1205673217773438e-05
First element of the array is 0.5938379332312543
Using PyMemoryView_FromMemory
Elapsed time: 2.1696090698242188e-05
First element of the array is 0.5938379332312543
```

Comment: You should probably use *NumPy*'s *C* *API* directly and skip the *Python* layer completely.